# Date selection doesn't work in Firefox for angular material date picker

Tags: angular, firefox, datepicker, angular-material

When I try to select a date on the mat datepicker in Firefox, it doesn't make a date selection at all and goes back to its initial state.

I have multiple date pickers on the page and the functionality works perfectly well in Edge and Chrome. It is only Firefox where none of the controls / selection works

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" [matDatepicker]="picker" (focus)="picker.open()" (click)="picker.open()" readonly [formControl]="dateFormControl" >
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

I need help making the date selection happen on Firefox too

Comment: can you write your code ? so that anybody can check the issue properly

Comment: Added my code with the question.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput type="string" [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" [matDatepicker]="picker" (focus)="picker.open()" (click)="picker.open()" readonly [formControl]="dateFormControl" >
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

it should work

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. In all other browsers, the change event seems to get called. But in Firefox the change event doesn't get called at all

Comment: this.dateFormControl.valueChanges.subscribe((val) =>
    {
      this.rowItem.validFrom = val;
      this.componentParent.updateRow(this.rowNode, this.rowItem);
    });

Comment: can you try once with (ngModelChange)="yourFunction()"

Comment: Tried this too.. Yet again the change event doesn't get triggered. When i click on any date in the date picked in Firefox, the calendar simply closes and doesn't make any selection at all. The same behavior is noticed if we try to change the month on the calendar too

Answer (score 0):

If you move focus and click events to mat-form-field the click event works properly but focus event does not work.